# Nested callbacks run asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

How can I get over this asynchronous code and also pass values between callbacks?

Here totalfee variable is set in first callback but is not accessible in second callback.

```
 var totalfee;
 SetFee.find({standard:standard}, function(error,document){
  totalfee = document[0].totalfee;
  CollectFee.find({ssn:ssn}, function(error,document){
        if(typeof(document[0])=='undefined'){
          let paidfee=0;
          var cfee = new CollectFee({
            ssn:ssn,
            paidfee:paidfee
          });
          cfee.save();
        }
        else {
          showpaid=document[0].paidfee;
          console.log(ssn,name,totalfee,showpaid);
          res.redirect('/fees/cfees?ssn='+ssn+'&name='+name+'&totalfee='+totalfee+'&paidfee='+showpaid);
        }
  });            
});
```

[REFERENCE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGxjK.png)

Comment: IMHO it should be accessible. Check its value when its been set.

Comment: it definitively has to be accessible, weather it has a value asigned is another story.

Comment: It must be accessible if the instructions are executed one after other but here other instruction are excecuted before totalfee=document[0].totalfee could

Comment: @Adder I think it is a case of callback hell. Do you have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: Did you put in a `console.log("totalfee set to ", totalfee);` after `totalfee = document[0].totalfee;`

Comment: @Adder Yes I did and it returned value as expected but in second callback it returned undefined

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these pointers will guide you somewhere.

(1) Use `findOne` since you are expecting one document.

(2) Use better names for your variables e.g. `document` is ambiguous.

(3) Add `console.log` statements for debugging.

(4) Probably good idea to also check `err` to see if any errors show up. Usually errors only occur when you insert/update/delete though.

```
SetFee.findOne({ standard: standard }, function (err, setFee) {
    console.log('setFee', setFee)
    let totalfee = setFee.totalfee;

    CollectFee.findOne({ ssn: ssn }, function (err, collectFee) {
        console.log('collectFee', collectFee)
        if (!collectFee) {
            // use of return is to stop the 'else' part from executing
            return CollectFee.create({ ssn: ssn, paidfee: 0 }, function (err, collectFee) {
                // do something here or your route handler will hang!
            });
        }
        let showpaid = collectFee.paidfee;
        console.log(ssn, name, totalfee, showpaid);
        res.redirect('/fees/cfees?ssn=' + ssn + '&name=' + name + '&totalfee=' + totalfee + '&paidfee=' + showpaid);
    });            
});
```

Comment: Clean code! But it didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Vishnudev Explain. Are the `console.log` producing correct outputs? Is it hanging? Where does it fail?

Comment: If I console.log(totalfee) in first callback it returns expected output, but in second callback it returns null .

Comment: @Vishnudev Weird... the scope of `totalfee` should be accessible throughout the first callback (including the second callback). You're not doing anything else, right? First try changing `let` to `var`. If no luck, then try doing `console.log(setFee.totalfee)` from within the second callback.

Comment: XD I actually tried everything you said beforehand. No success! Do you have any idea how I can implement this in Async.js?

Comment: @Vishnudev So what happened when you did `console.log(setFee.totalfee)`? I honestly have no idea why any of these things wouldn't work as I've done these things many times. And yours is a pretty simple example. I don't think async.js would really help you but if you really want to go for it, you are probably looking for [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall). Kindly edit your question with your revised code (probably below the original).

Comment: @Vishnudev Add also `console.log(err)` to both callbacks -- you may have an error somewhere.